# C# cannot implicitly convert type T to type T

Tags: .net-3.5, lambda, extension-methods

my method:

```
public TableFilled<TKey, TRow> getTera()
    {

        Func<TablesFilled<TKey,TRow>> _getTera=new Func<TablesFilled<TKey,TRow>>(
        ()=>{return (TablesFilled<TKey,TRow>) chGetTera();});

       //Above does not compile says: Cannot convert type 
       //'AcapsVerify.FunctionalTables.TableFilled<TKey,TRow>' to 
       //'AcapsVerify.FunctionalTables.TablesFilled<TKey,TRow>'
       // the line below has the same blue underline error.
       return _getTera.TimeAndReport("Finished Teradata",OutputIfListener);

       // this works fine
       return chGetTera;
    }
```

The static method it calls

```
public static T TimeAndReport<T>(this Func<T> timedFunc, String reportLead, Action<String> reporterAction)
    {
        T result;
        var s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        result = timedFunc();
        s.Stop();
        reporterAction(reportLead + " in " + s.WholePartOnly());
        return result;
    }
```

return class definition:

```
public class TableFilled<TKey,TRow> where TRow: STeraRow<TKey>
```

Comment: To put this into more context, I'm making a functional table comparison program where one is the master table and one is the copy. Functionally a filled table is different from the class that builds it. I'd like to have all the table factories report how long they took if anyone is listening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what is the difference between a TableFilled type and a TablesFilled type? Either you have a typo in your return type or you do not have an implicit conversion between the two types.

Comment: sorry they have the same signature, I edited it to have TableFilled showing

Comment: But you can't convert from a TablesFilled to a TableFilled even if they've got the same definition - that's the problem. Do you *really* need to have two class names which only vary by a letter in the middle in the first place?

Comment: holy cow... yup that was the problem any suggestions for a better name for the filled pair of tables that is ready for comparing?

Answer (score 4):

You can typecast by using object.

```
return (T)(object)(result);
```

For me it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference comes from not all items in the process having the `where TRow : STeraRow<TKey>` designation.

Comment: even the extension method has to have the same restriction?

Comment: apparently not, it's compiling now that I fixed the type typo

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the Func should have been returning a FilledTable instead of FilledTables

```
    abstract protected TableFilled<TKey, TRow> chGetTera();

    public TableFilled<TKey, TRow> getTera()
    {

        Func<TableFilled<TKey,TRow>> _getTera=new Func<TableFilled<TKey,TRow>>(
        ()=>{return  chGetTera();});

return _getTera.TimeAndReport("Finished Teradata",OutputIfListener);

 //return chGetTera();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert.ChangeType** should be a solution for your questions:

```
(T) Convert.ChangeType(yourObject, typeof(T));
```